# How can I convert a complex if/ifelse/else condition to a readable Object Literal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I rewrote my code to what I think I was trying to accomplish.  I cannot wrap my head around using object literals as an alternative to if/else or switch.  How would you convert the if/else condition to an Object Literal below?

```
let bobRes = "A123";
//stored password in database
let sPass = "A1234";
let qState = "q1";

function responseHandler(bobResValue, sPassValue, qStateValue) {
  if (sPass === "" && qStateValue === "q1") {

    return "Create a new password using five digits.";
  } else if (bobResValue.length !== 5 && qStateValue === "q1") {

    return "Password is too short!";
  } else if (bobResValue !== sPassValue) {

    return "Wrong Password";
  } else if (bobResValue === sPass) {

    return "Correct Password";
  } else {

    return "You must enter a password to continue?";
  }
}

let finalResponse = responseHandler(bobRes, sPass, qState);
console.log(finalResponse)
```

My attempt to convert to object literal!  But I'm stuck on the logic...

```
let bobRes = "A123";
//stored password in database
let sPass = "A1234";
 


function responseHandler(bobResValue) {
  let respObj = {

    "None": "You must enter a password." 
   
  }
  let respObj2 = {
      passWordLength: (bobResValue) => bobResValue.length != 5,
  }

let respObj3 = {
      passWordLength: (bobResValue) => bobResValue === 5,
  }

  respObj[bobResValue] ?? respObj2[passWordLength]?? "You must enter a password to continue!";
}

let finalResponse = responseHandler(bobRes, sPass, qState);
console.log(finalResponse)
```

Comment: Think "functional programming".

Comment: e.g. `passWordLength: (password) => password.length != 5`

Comment: What do you mean by "turn to an object literal"? *What* do you want to turn into an object literal, and what kind of object do you want to create with it?

Comment: Like FZs, I’m also confused at what kind of output are you looking for — currently `responseHandler` always returns a single string value, and from your description alone I don’t understand what objects have to do with it. I _think_ user Barmar above me is trying to hint you towards a direction of returning an object with multiple properties (e.g. `passWordLength`) that are all boolean values (true/false); is that what you’re after?

Comment: Oftentimes when people talk about refactoring if-else blocks or switch statements into object literals, they’re doing _pattern matching_ by using the ability to lookup values from an object using keys, but I think that doesn’t make much sense here and thus if you (instead of the above) are trying to do something similar, you might’ve misunderstood how object literals can be used here.

Comment: As I was building my application I was stumped by all the if/else statements that I created!  I'm still new to programming even newer to JavaScript!  I do understand the examples on pattern matching I seen on MDN and other tutorials!  So I was trying to see if bobResp met the criteria of the password format!  I should of specified that from the beginning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give up! These kinds of refactors will teach you to identify problems with how you are thinking about the program and permanently unlock new techniques.

This is a practical use case for the `Either` monad. Don't let unfamiliar terms scare you. Here we demonstrate the technique in a lo-fi way as `ok` and `err`. If you have any questions, just ask -

```js
const ok = value => ({
  chain: f => f(value),
  get: (ifOk, _) => ifOk(value)
})

const err = value => ({
  chain: _ => err(value),
  get: (_, ifErr) => ifErr(value)
})

const isEmpty = s => (s === "")
  ? err("create a new password using five digits")
  : ok(s)

const isTooShort = s => (s.length != 5 || Number.isNaN(Number.parseInt(s)))
  ? err("password is not five digits")
  : ok(s)

const isMatch = match => s => (s !== match)
  ? err("wrong password")
  : ok(s)

function validate(pass, match) {
  return isEmpty(pass)
    .chain(isTooShort)
    .chain(isMatch(match))
    .get(console.log, console.error)
}

validate("", "foo")
validate("123", "123")
validate("12345", "9876")
validate("12345", "12345")
```

Replace `console.log` with the identity function, `v => v`, to have `validate` return the valid password instead of logging it to the console.

Optionally replace `console.error` with `msg => { throw Error(msg) }` to have `validate` throw an error that corresponds to the specific failure.

Comment: @QuackEDuck, thank you for your contribution. It differs enough from this post to warrant its own separate posting. In the future, be careful to use words like "I", "me", or "my" when editing some else's work as you do not intend (I assume) to speak on behalf of the original author.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me.  I was aware of this rule for regular posts, but didn't realize it extended to Community Wiki posts as well.  I apologize if my edit made it look like you personally were endorsing my solution:  you assumed correctly that was not my intent!  I appreciate your understanding and will avoid making this kind of edit in the future.